I can't resolve this plugin error in build.gradle
I'm trying to create a project in Dart and Flutter using android studio, but this error won't let me move forward.



I've tried a few things I found on the internet but none of them worked.

Hi, please Show both build.gradle files, settings.gradle and gradle-wrapper.properties

It is as the error message says: You can't have a directory-path with non-ASCII characters on Windows, which I'd assume it is. Close the project and rename from Portuguese "programação" to eg. English (ASCII) "programming". And also that plugins block most definitely also does not belong into settings.gradle, but the root-level build.gradle - and then without "version" and "apply false" into the module-level build.gradle.
